# PHP Larvel enum select option

Tags: php, laravel, select, enums

I have a problem with enum select option.
that's my UsersTable

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('blocked')->default(false);
            $table->enum('rule', ['CLIENT', 'ADMIN', 'DEVELOPER'])->default('CLIENT');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

That's my UpdateRequest function

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => ['nullable'],
            'last_name' => ['nullable'],
            'phone' => ['nullable'],
            'email' => ['nullable'],
            'blocked' => ['nullable'],
            'rule' => ['nullable'],
        ];
    }  
}
```

and now I want to make a select option in edit.blade.php

```
<select class="form-control" name="rule">
    @foreach(["CLIENT" => "Klient", "ADMIN" => "Admin", "DEVELOPER" => "Developer"] AS $rule => $ruleLabel)    
        <option value="{{ $rule }}" {{ old("rule", $users->rule == $rule ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $ruleLabel }}</option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
```

I created something like this, but is not working. Still can't change user role;/ Any sugestions?

Comment: ___I created something like this___ **??** So show us what you actually created!

Comment: share dump of user object

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your option tag like below and check again.

```
<option value="{{ $rule }}" @if($users->rule == $rule) selected @endif>{{ $ruleLabel }}</option>
```

Comment: I tried, but still not changing

Comment: Please check your $users->rule variable data

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<select class="form-control" name="rule">
@foreach(["CLIENT" => "Klient", "ADMIN" => "Admin", "DEVELOPER" => "Developer"] AS $rule => $ruleLabel)    
    <option value="{{ $rule }}" {{ old("rule", $users->rule) == $rule ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $ruleLabel }}</option>
 @endforeach
```

I changed just the option line:

```
<option value="{{ $rule }}" {{ old("rule", $users->rule) == $rule ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $ruleLabel }}</option>
```